# ngrok ERR_NGROK_702 Too Many Connections

Tags: ngrok

I'm using `ngrok` to put my web application online and make some tests. But, when I reload the page, the error `ERR_NGROK_702` (Too Many Connections) appears, like the image below.

[image: ngrok err_ngrok_702]

Is there any way to solve or avoid it instead of buying a paid plan?

How can I decrease the *inbound connection volume*, as said in the message?

Or the only way is to wait some minutes and try again?

I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/mmatczuk/go-http-tunnel it's self hosted open source ngrok alternative.

Comment: can I use this on windows?

Answer (score 8):

Just wait 1 minute or two and refresh. Optimize the number of connections made to the service or else pay to avoid this limitation.

Answer (score 8):

Use Localtunnel insted of ngrok. https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/

You don't have to change the URL every time.

```
1) npm install -g localtunnel

2) lt --port 8081 --subdomain "your desired domain name"
```

**`eg: lt --port 8081 --subdomain myshopifyapp`**

Answer (score 4):

Right now the tunnel provider (ngrok) has a limit of the number of connections or resources loaded in a given time. So, if you have a page with a lot of links to images, stylesheets, or scripts, you can go through the limit quickly.

Improving Live Links is something that we are wanting to do and are still working through the best way of going about this.

In the meantime, you have a couple of options:

Make use of a plugin to minify and/or lazy load assets so that the total number of assets is reduced for the various pages. Autoptimize 2 should help with this or a more advanced caching plugin like WP Rocket would also help.

Deploy a version of the site to a Demo site so that there aren’t any limits on the number of assets that are downloaded

Comment: What can I do though if a page has some images on it? It will immediately brick if the server serves those files even if they're basically small icons. To minify the JS won't help in a case like that (aka my use case)